# How can I protect against my laptop being stolen? Can it share its location?

Tags: 20.04, security

In case my laptop gets stolen, is it possible to use some kind of service or something that shares its location at all times? In other words, what to do against the thievery?

Comment: I used to use a service called "Prey" which supported Linux but I haven't looked at it in many years. Looks like there is still a free version. https://preyproject.com/

Comment: It depends on your threat model. Basically, if it's stolen, there is no reason why it wouldn't be wiped, so anything that keeps on working then would have to be BIOS based (such as LoJack, which is a subscription service).

Comment: You can protect your data on your laptop a bit with a BIOS password, a Grub password and Full Disk Encryption.

If you talk about retrival..
If your Laptop does not have GPS and a SIM slot installed, this will be a difficult task. 

Even if you have GPS and a SIM slot installed in your HW, chances are slim that the Thief will power it up long enough for you to get a "ping."

You'd have to forgo BIOS password, a Grub password and Full Disk Encryption because you'd need the Laptop to fully boot, for it to "phone home" (with whatever means).

Comment: Alternatively:

You can invest in these small GPS Trackers, like "GF-07". You could put that in your laptop bag. So if the bag gets stolen, you could track it.

Maybe, you could even fit that inside your laptop (its smaller than a lighter) and even connect it to USB, so that it keeps charging.

But thats out of scope on this website.

Comment: For many people the data and personal information in the laptop is more valuable than the hardware itself. Please edit your question and indicate if you care about the data in the laptop as some of the methods to protect the data will work against locating and retrieving the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Others had mention [Prey](https://preyproject.com/) (open source and freemium). You can also try [Pombo](https://github.com/BoboTiG/pombo/). But your question is *What to do against the thievery?*. This is more broad.

- **Avoid being robbed**

  - Use security/[Kensington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot) lock cable
  - Activate an alarm when stolen ("kill cord", pendrive or AC power removed). Something like [BusKill](https://fossbytes.com/buskill-diy-usb-kill-cable-locks-down-linux-laptop-if-stolen/) ([LAlarm](https://www.lalarm.com/) or [A.L.A.R.M.](http://alarm.sourceforge.net/) equivalent for Linux¹).
- **Avoid others access to your data**

  - [Full disk encryption LUKS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019): This and a backup are probably the best things to do. Hardware is replaceable, your data probably not.
  - Always lock your laptop (and use a strong password)
- **Get your laptop back**

  - Engrave contact info so they could reach you if it ends on honest hands.
  - Prey/Pombo: Probably a little naive.
  - Add a RFID tag for tracking/SmartTag
  - Could be useful to save on a safe location your *make*, *model* and *serial numbers* (`sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number`/`-t chassis`, `lsblk --nodeps -no serial /dev/sda`)

¹ Please comment for more/better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [prey](https://preyproject.com/how-it-works/).
Prey is a multi-platform tracking software that allows the tracking of up to three devices for free. It uses geolocation methodologies to track your device based on the IP of the connection that your set up device is using to access the internet, or the GPS sensor if your laptop has one.

Of course any such service can only offer limited security on a laptop, irrespective of the operating system in use and comes with a privacy trade-off. A thief could always swap the drive..

Answer (score 0):

Answer would depend on the laptop. For example ***if*** you had a Dell notebook with SIM card slot:

- [Installing Your Wireless SIM Card and Activating Your Mobile Broadband Service](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000132397/installing-your-wireless-sim-card-and-activating-your-mobile-broadband-service)

... You could theoretically program it to make a call on startup or resume.

If you don't have a laptop with SIM card connected to broadband service this this article:

- [6 Laptop Theft Recovering Software With GPS Location Tracking And SpyCam](https://www.geckoandfly.com/1875/how-to-recover-your-lost-or-stolen-laptop/)

Provides an overview of the six most popular anti-theft programs:

- 01 – PreyProject | GPS / SpyCam | Free | Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS
- 02 – Hidden Anti Theft | GPS / SpyCam | Paid | macOS and iOS
- 03 – Absolute DDS [ Enterprise ] | GPS | Windows, macOS, Android
- 04 – Pombo [ Open Source ] | GPS | Windows, MmacOS, Android
- 05 – Norton Mobile Security | GPS / SpyCam | iOS
- 06 – DriveStrike | Locate / Encrypt | iOS / Android

Answer (score -3):

full answer (and tutorial) for sharing PC GPS:

- go to settigs/privacy/location and enable location services
- install wayland (if you didn't installed/had built-in)
- install anbox (it run only in wayland, so you needed to install that)
- setup anbox kernel (just t be able to run app on that)

now you have second system inside ubuntu. now we need to setup anbox to share location:

- download android's app for sharing GPS (there are many, you choose what to take, i won't decide for you)
- install and run app inside anbox. wifi, another networks and GPS should be immediately enabled on "android" as you enabled on PC, so just remember to NOT shutdown PC, cause it could kill anbox and this GPS sharer as you installed. :) PS: a good fix to be able to close laptop and prevent sleeping is installing and enabling caffeine. ;)

Comment: Computers rarely ship with a GPS installed, and a stolen machine will not be able to connect to an unknown network without interaction, which will likely be blocked by a locked session. How would this work at all?

Comment: gps in ubuntu os based on wifi network. i'd think more about that second thing :/ i also don't have any plugin for that and it's available in settings...

Comment: and about connecting networks - if device'd have access to open hotspots - there it's possible to create script for that

Comment: As a laptop thief, I would likely also have a cell phone configured to broadcast with a Starbucks or McDonald's WiFi SSID so that I can collect authentication tokens for various services from unwitting victims in my vicinity. The laptop will also connect to that when trying to phone home, and no message will be sent ... 